# Why does the output appear black?

Tags: fortran

- Operating System : Windows 10
- Compiler : XStart
- Command when running the program : pgf90 prgramname.f90
- running program command : a.out

Program code I wrote :

```
Program silta
implicit none
CHARACTER :: Str_1 = " For", Str_2 =" tran", z
z = Str_1 // Str_2 // " -90"
print *, z
end program silta
```

When I run this program, there is no result and only black space.
Probably the result of the problem is the Fortran-90, but how do I get it to print properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
CHARACTER :: Str_1 = " For", Str_2 =" tran", z
```

declares 3 character variables, each one character long.  What you get, therefore, is `str1 == " "`, `str2 == " "` and `z` unset.  Then this line

```
z = Str_1 // Str_2 // " -90"
```

is interpreted as

```
z = " " // " " // " -90"
```

but only the first character, which is a space, gets into `z`.  And that's what you see when you print it out, or rather, that's what you don't see, it's just a space.

Go back to your Fortran tutorial and learn about character lengths, perhaps start with

```
CHARACTER(len=8) :: Str_1 = " For", Str_2 =" tran", z
```

As VladimirF has commented, learn also the intrinsic function `trim` for getting rid of trailing spaces in character variables.  There are other useful intrinsic string functions too, worthy of your research.

Comment: It will also be good to try `TRIM(Str_1) // TRIM(Str_2) // " -90"`, I am sure it is covered in some duplicate and in many textbooks and tutorials. That is relevant to the experiment with `CHARACTER(30)`.